# How to sort data in descending order cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

Hello i am new in cakephp i'm facing the issue of viewing data i have a user table  relation with  other tables and i'm viewing all data in same page but i did not know how to to show other table array data in descending order with same find user function .

```
public function fillprofile($id = null) {
    $id = $this->Auth->user('id');

    $data = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => $id)));
     $this->set('data', $data);

}
```

User table relation with Userdata table

```
 [User] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [username] => 
        [onboarding_user] => 0
        [email] => test@gmail.com
        [password] => 95e14332b6a34e6c4c5e196c497e855b0ceb95a5
        [uni_code] => 7L1H
        [fullname] => Alex sharma
        [profile_img] => img/profile/1504870214_e211498fca9dd372e0db69f23b31756e.png
        [description] => Developer 
        [updated_date_time] => 2017-09-08 08:21:31

        [created_date_time] => 2017-07-06 16:23:27
    )


[Userdata] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 13
                [user_id] => 2
                [position_title] => Developer
                [company_name] => TEST 2
                [created_date_time] => 2017-08-18 13:19:53
                [updated_date_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00

            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 19
                [user_id] => 2
                [position_title] => Angular Js
                [company_name] => TEST
                [created_date_time] => 2017-09-08 16:31:48
                [updated_date_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            )
    )
```

Comment: in relational table you can write 'order' => 'Userdata.position_title DESC', as example.

Comment: why the unnecessary tags? what's this question have to do with JS, angular, or AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Change your fillprofile function to include order param:

```
public function fillprofile($id = null) {
    $id = $this->Auth->user('id');

    $data = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.' 
            . $this->User->primaryKey => $id), 
            'order'=>'Userdata.position_title DESC'));

    $this->set('data', $data);
}
```

More can be read about the find optional parameters here: 
https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html